# jQuery History Plugin replacing URL wrong

Tags: jquery, html, history

So I am using the jQuery History plugin (http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/).
Also, I wrote the script below to switch through pages.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Define the default pagetitle.
    var defaultTitle = "MySite / ";

    // Set a default pagetitle.
    document.title = defaultTitle + "Homepage";

    // Switch the page.
    function load(page) {
        $("#contentHolder").fadeOut("fast",function(){
            $('#contentHolder').load("content/"+ page +".php");
            $("#contentHolder").fadeIn("fast");
        });
    }

    // Function to shorten the scriptsize.
    function reduceSize(mainUrl) {
        // Define the URL.
        var url = mainUrl;
        // Replace the URL in the address bar.
        url = url.replace(/^.*#/, '');
        // Load the page.
        $.history.load(url);
        return false;
    }

    // Enable history.
    $.history.init(function(url) {
        load(url == "" ? "general/homepage" : url);
    });

    // Make the menu useful.
    $('.switch_homepage').live('click', function(e) {
        reduceSize("general/homepage");
        document.title = defaultTitle + "Homepage";
    });

});
```

My problem is that whenever I click the "Homepage" button, the page switches to:
http://www.domain.com/#general%2Fhomepage
while it should switch to
http://www.domain.com/#general/homepage

Can anybody figure out why it converts the slash to an HTML format?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the plugin source (https://raw.github.com/tkyk/jquery-history-plugin/master/jquery.history.js), it looks like it's doing the encoding for you.

```
function initObjects(options) {
    options = $.extend({
            unescape: false
        }, options || {});

    locationWrapper.encoder = encoder(options.unescape);

    function encoder(unescape_) {
        if(unescape_ === true) {
            return function(hash){ return hash; };
        }
        if(typeof unescape_ == "string" &&
           (unescape_ = partialDecoder(unescape_.split("")))
           || typeof unescape_ == "function") {
            return function(hash) { return unescape_(encodeURIComponent(hash)); };
        }
        return encodeURIComponent;
    }

    function partialDecoder(chars) {
        var re = new RegExp($.map(chars, encodeURIComponent).join("|"), "ig");
        return function(enc) { return enc.replace(re, decodeURIComponent); };
    }
}
```

You can try setting an option of `unescape: true` in your initialization, see if that works.

Comment: This works perfectly. Does this cause a script to be unstable or insecure? Thank you.

Comment: No, but be careful as certain characters are not allowed in the URL and might mess it up.  However, as long as you control the URL it shouldn't be too big of a deal.  As with all things, don't let users persist changes to the page through the URL (so they could screw someone else over via direct linking), never use `eval` and don't trust any input from the client.  Follow this and you should be fine.